# Percona Xtrabackup fails during backup

Tags: mysql, percona, innobackupex

When i try to perform a backup using Percona innobackupex, i get the following error:

```
 george@db-pxc-1 [~] [17:50] sudo innobackupex --user=root  --password=secret --host=127.0.0.1  ~/Data
160830 17:50:34 innobackupex: Starting the backup operation

IMPORTANT: Please check that the backup run completes successfully.
           At the end of a successful backup run innobackupex
           prints "completed OK!".

160830 17:50:35  version_check Connecting to MySQL server with DSN 'dbi:mysql:;mysql_read_default_group=xtrabackup;host=127.0.0.1;port=3306' as 'kkuser'  (using password: YES).
Failed to connect to MySQL server: DBI connect(';mysql_read_default_group=xtrabackup;host=127.0.0.1;port=3306','root',...) failed: Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES) at - line 1314
160830 17:50:35 Connecting to MySQL server host: 127.0.0.1, user: root, password: set, port: 3306, socket: (null)
Failed to connect to MySQL server: Access denied for user 'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES).
george@db-pxc-1 [~] [17:50]
```

The xtrabackup version is:

```
george@db-pxc-1 [~] [17:58] xtrabackup --version
xtrabackup version 2.3.3 based on MySQL server 5.6.24 Linux (x86_64) (revision id: 525ca7d)
```

Perl version:

```
george@db-pxc-1 [~] [18:03] perl -MDBD::mysql -e 'print $DBD::mysql::VERSION'
4.016
```

The server is running Debian Squeeze. I use this command all the time on ubuntu machines to perform backups and never had a problem before.

The MySQL is not PXC, but regular Percona server. And i have plenty of disk space and memory.

Comment: You are right. The user only had @'localhost' privileges. But after adding @'127.0.0.1' and also @'%', the backup works fine now. Thanks @MichielB

Answer (score 0):

innobackupex : Related with linux file limit configuration.

Increase your file limit and try again

$ulimit -n 999999